# How to write "a" in semiverbatim environment with ngerman without writing "{}a"?

Tags: beamer, verbatim, babel

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Umlauts}
\begin{semiverbatim}
Wrong:
"a"

Right:
"{}a"
\end{semiverbatim}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex. This is probably related to a similar question: [How to prevent angle brackets beautification in semiverbatim environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119312/how-to-prevent-angle-brackets-beautification-in-semiverbatim-environment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can deactivate the special meaning of `"` done by `babel`.

This can be achieved by

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{semiverbatim}{\shorthandoff{"}}
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{semiverbatim}{\shorthandoff{"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Umlauts}
\begin{semiverbatim}
Wrong:
"a"

Right:
"{}a"
\end{semiverbatim}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```